# Free text search using Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I got around 200m records having 20 columns in a relational db now. I am trying to setup a free text search functionality supporting both AND and OR functions from a web page against this dataset using Solr. I should be able to a search string or combination of strings from a text field on the web page.  Example: If I enter "database lookup" all records having these any of this string on any of the columns should show up. If I enter "database+lookup" all records having both strings on any of the columns should show up. Can I implement this using Solr? Thanks in advance on any help on this.

Comment: Check out the Solr tutorial - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/solr-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes. Define a `copyField` with `src` set to `*` and the destination set to `_text_` or something similar. Search against the `_text_` field. If you want to give different weights to different columns, keep them as separate fields in Solr and use the edismax handler together with `qf` (with all the fields listed and their weights) to search.

Comment: Thanks much MatsLindh